# Laurent series of a complex multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, laurent-series

Suppose $f(x,y)$ to be a function  of variables $x$, $y$
$$
f(x,y)=\frac{-\left(\pi^{2}-4x^{2}\right)y\left(\pi^{2}-4y^{2}\right)\left(\pi^{2}\cos2x-4x(x-\pi\sin x)\right)}{\pi\left(\left(x^{2}+y^{2}\right)\left(64x^{2}y^{2}+4\pi^{4}\right)-64\pi^{2}x^{2}y^{2}+\pi\left(\pi^{2}-4y^{2}\right)^{2}\sin x(\pi\sin x-4x)\right)}.
$$
For $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$ is $f(x,y)\rightarrow-\infty$. How to
find the Laurent series at $(0,0)$ for such complex form of the multivariate
function? Is it possible, or, only some numeric approach is available?

There are many samples of the elementary functions but more complicated examples are missing.

Mathematica provides the following solution:

```
f = -((Pi^2 - 4*x^2)*y*(Pi^2 - 4*y^2)*(Pi^2*Cos[2*x] - 4*x*(x - Pi*Sin[x])))/
     (Pi*(-64*Pi^2*x^2*y^2 + 4*Pi^4*(x^2 + y^2) + 64*x^2*y^2*(x^2 + y^2) + 
      Pi*(Pi^2 -4*y^2)^2*Sin[x]*(-4*x + Pi*Sin[x])))
Normal[Series[f, {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 3}]]
```

$$x^2 \left(\left(\frac{16}{\pi ^4}-\frac{16}{\pi ^5}-\frac{4}{\pi ^3}\right) y^3+\frac{\frac{\pi }{4}-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}+\frac{\pi ^3}{16}}{y^3}+\left(\frac{12}{\pi ^3}-\frac{8}{\pi ^2}+\frac{1}{\pi }\right) y+\frac{2-\frac{3}{\pi }-\frac{\pi }{4}}{y}\right)+\frac{y}{\pi }-\frac{\pi }{4 y} + O(4).$$

Thanks for your help.